# Acer laptop won't recognize SSDs

Tags: ssd, acer-aspire

I bought an Acer Aspire e1-472g-6844, and am trying to replace the HDD with SSD. I have tried 2 different SSDs (both from Crucial, but different models) and neither one works. I have tried 3 different HDDs and all of them work.

---

Details:

-BIOS recognizes both SSDs and HDDs as potential boot drives

-Windows 8.1 installation discs work on the HDDs, but doesn't even boot when there's a SSD

-Ubuntu 14.04 LiveUSB runs, but GParted detects no drives when there's a SSD ; works fine when there's a HDD.

---

I spoke with the tech support at Crucial and Acer.

Crucial said the SSD should work in my model of laptop ; after many failed suggestions as to how to fix it, they told me they couldn't help me anymore.

Acer said they have never tried using a SSD in this model, and therefore don't know if it works.

---

I should also mention that I know both SSDs work, because I've tried them in an ASUS laptop. My OS is currently on one of them.

So, should I buy a different brand of SSD or will the laptop not work with any? Is there a certain brand of SSD I should go with next time?

Thanks!

Comment: Different models of SSDs shouldn't matter, as they all use the same SATA specifications and protocols. Technically it should "just work".

Comment: Do you have any BIOS settings that with have anything like SATA, IDE, AHCI, in them?

Comment: The only setting that's anything like that is xHCI vs eHCI, which I believe has something to do with USB. I tried this both ways and it didn't seem to change anything.